# exporting rdlc report to excel or pdf making server cpu to go high

Tags: rdlc, reportviewer

I have been having an issue with report viewer, for one of the reports,when we are exporting large report to excel or pdf, it opens up in a new window and process forever and it also causing server CPU utilization to 100%. Does anyone have come across this kind of issue?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same thing when exporting RDLC to excel.  Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution.. We have one report with lot of data rendering on single page, I have put multiple page breaks to split the data in different pages(ex: I had issue when the whole bunch of data is rendered on 3 pages, I have put page break, so the information split into 10 pages, rendering to Excel or PDF was quick)